# One-off import into Journey entry source

Tags: journeybuilder, dataextensions, import

quick question re: Journey entry source.

Currently I populate the entry source DE with contacts from a SQL query automation.

I've got a handful of records I need to insert into that journey (in the beginning).  Can I simply import them into the DE via the import wizard?  Will they be treated as if they were inserted into the DE from the automation?

If so, I imagine I will also have to do an add/update to the historical DE I use to check for changes in opt-out status, right?

TIA

Answer (score 0):

Uploading the records into the Entry DE outside of the normal JB connected Automation will not feed them into the Journey.

Can you import the records into the DE that your query is using in the FROM statement?

Or create a new query that pull in those records and appends to the Journey Entry DE, add that to the Automation for a single run then remove the query if it's not going to be a regular occurance.